# Android studio. RecyclerViewAdapter.CardView

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview, cardview

CardView размещаются вертикально, одна под другой.
CardView выравниваются по левому краю родительского элемента.
В макете CardView ширина задана:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

У родительского элемента

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Мне необходимо, что бы часть CardView выравнивалась по левому краю часть по правому.
На данный момент в принципе не могу добиться того, что бы CardView (некоторые или все) выравнивались по правому краю.

Куда копать?

С Уважением
Mr.Zn

Сдвиги есть, но... По порядку:
RecyclerViewAdapter размещается внутри фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    <...>
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    <...>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

После того как, в качестве app:layoutManager был указан "android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager", а в макете CardView был задан параметр `android:layout_gravity="end"`, при просмотре макета в AndroidStudio CardView сместилась к правому краю, но после запуска на эмуляторе CradView все так же расположены по левому краю.

Так же пробовал в макете CardView использовать следующие параметры

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
card_view:layout_anchorGravity="right"
```

Результата нет, после запуска приложения на эмуляторе CardView расположены у левого края экрана.

На данный момент основной вопрос, как в принципе добиться того, что бы CardView размещались по правому краю.

---

Всем спасибо, проблема решена.
Отдельная благодарность Романычу за ссылку.

Comment: Попробуй обернуть свой кард Вью в другой лейаут, может быть Relative Layout и привязать его к правому краю. А для того чтоб часть отображать слева, а часть справа создай разные Вью холдеры

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, Вы предлагаете изменять макет CardView,

Comment: Ну если тебе необходимо чтоб это был кард Вью то просто оберни, а если у тебя макет не требует теней и других плюшек кард Вью, то просто изменить.

Comment: В общем, [есть такая тема](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftrashbox.ru%2Fifiles%2F442549_67e418_screenshot_08%2Fmysms-sms-text-messaging-sync-6.5.1-9.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftrashbox.ru%2Flink%2Fmysms-android&docid=G3burxD9AXTlUM&tbnid=hV2V00XvikTeJM%3A&vet=1&w=506&h=900&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim), одно сообщение отображается справа, другое слева. Или я не туда копаю и это делается не через CardVCiew? Тогда как? Решение не прошу, но направление... укажите

Comment: Ну я же тебе написал. Попробуй создать дар разных макета. И два разных Вью холдера. В адаптере есть метод getItemViewType, с помощью него ты можешь определить тип входящих данных и по разному из отобразить.

Comment: Эта тема это два элемента. Которые чередуются в адаптере. Один элент имеет разметку слува, второй справа. Такую шляпу можно сделать ручками, но, думаю, хватает готовых библиотек. Копайте в сторону го овых решений

Comment: https://blog.sendbird.com/android-chat-tutorial-building-a-messaging-ui

Comment: @Mr.Zn Гуглится на chat recyclerview